# MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019:

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I installed VS 2010 Pro and trying to set up OpenCV v2.4.8; since I started setting up OpenCV, my basic C++ projects won't work.

For framing an assistance response, I'm relatively new to programming, visual studio, and libraries, though I have done a bunch of work with MATLAB.

This program fails:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {        
        return 0;
    }
```

with Output:

```
    MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

    D:\...\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Cpp_Learning\Debug\Cpp_Learning.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

All guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You've set up a Win32 program, which expects [WinMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: When you created the project in Visual Studio, you told it to create a Windows project. Create it again as a Console project instead.

Comment: Awesome, thanks,  I appreciate your patience.  I really feel like a super-noob.